# vscode version 1.23 debugging node

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep getting exceptions when debugging using vscode.

```
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: Cannot find module 'bufferutil'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
```

This just started when I upgraded to 1.23.  My launch.json looks as follows:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/bin/www"
}
```

It seems as though the path is no longer set the `${workspaceFolder}` and some but not all of the node_modules can be found.

Also:

```
Exception has occurred: SyntaxError
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

When trying to display a jade page.  All works fine if I start node from the command line.  I can start node manually and use auto attach, but I can't start and debug using the 'debug' command.

Debugging worked fine prior to version 1.23

Comment: Also, I'm trying to launch node form an angular cli project.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue with websocket, 
see related here: ["Error: Cannot find module" when using browserify to bundle a socket.io dependency with --node flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475215/error-cannot-find-module-when-using-browserify-to-bundle-a-socket-io-dependen/37412727)

**answer is :**

There are 2 optional modules that can be installed along side with the ws module. These modules are binary addons which improve certain operations, but as they are binary addons they require compilation which can fail if no c++ compiler is installed on the host system.

```
npm install --save-optional bufferutil
npm install --save-optional utf-8-validate
```

see more here: https://github.com/websockets/ws#opt-in-for-performance